# How can a transformation be linear transformation without linearity?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

My teacher at the University gave me a question I could not understand completely. Here is the question:

> Let $T: \mathbb R^3 \to P[x]$ be a linear transformation with $$T([1, 0,
> 0])=x+1, \quad T([0, 1, 0])=x^2-x, \quad T([0, 0, 1])=x^2,$$ find
>   $T([a, b, c])$, also find the standard matrix $A$ for the
>   transformation.

The part that I did not understand is that how can $T([0, 1, 0])$ and $T([0, 0, 1])$ be linear since they have $x^2$. Also the $T([1, 0, 0])$ term has a constant. Those violate the linear transformation rules. Don't they?

Comment: Something wrong here. I think the  definition of $T$ is supposed to be $T[1,0,0]=x+1$ etc.

Comment: The question is not clear, in the sense $x$ in the domain refers to a real number, whereas the $x$ in the image refers to the variable in which the polynomial is written. There is something missing and/or a case of bad notation.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy is probably right. The $x$ in the domain vectors sould be $1$. Then it makes sense as the object on the RHS of the assignments are single vectors of the target space (polynomials in $x$).

Comment: @mattecapu let's assume those vectors are 1. But still I am confused with the linearity.

Comment: @immustafa: you must fix the question then.

Comment: This is one reason I prefer to never write polynomial indeterminates as $x$ (or worse $\lambda$), but as $X$. They are not (unknown) numbers, nor do they stand for numbers. There is no value but $X$ (and $X^2$ is its square).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As

$$[a,b,c]=a[1,0,0]+b[0,1,0]+c[0,0,1],$$

by linearity

$$T([a,b,c])=aT([1,0,0])+bT([0,1,0])+cT([0,0,1])=a(x+1)+b(x^2-x)+cx^2.$$

The linearity is not on $x$, but on $a,b,c$.

Comment: I now understand the point. Thank you.

Comment: What about the rest of the question? Is the standard transformation matrix a 3 by 1 matrix with elements $x+1$, $x^2-x$, $x^2$ ?

Comment: @immustafa: I don't know what they call the "standard matrix".

Answer (score 0):

How can $T([1,0,0])$ be linear? It's not linear; nobody said  it *was* linear. Here $T([1,0,0])$ is a vector, and it makes no sense to say a vector is linear.

$T$ is linear, not $T(v)$ for a vector $v$.

Answer (score -1):

Linearity is nothing more or less than requiring  $T(u+v)=T(u) +(v), T(au)=aT(u)$. This does not rule out
$T(u)=x+1$.

In fact consider the function $M\colon P[x]\to P[x]$ which has the effect of multiplying anything by $x^2+3x+1$ (or any random, fixed polynomial).

$M(f(x)+g(x) )= M(f(x) ) + M(g(x))$. ANd M(af(x) ) = aM(f(x)).

Can see  $M(1)= x^2+3x+1$, a quadratic function! $M$ satisfies the requirement of linear transformation, Perfectly alright.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain the fault in the answer?